# Django - Foreignkey and Many to Many References - How to Know Number of Queries?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How do I know if Django is running multiple queries when fetching a model that contains relations?

Here is an example:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):

    '''...the stuff...'''

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    something = models.ForeignKeyField(ModelOne)

    '''...all the things...'''

class ModelThree(models.Model):
    something_elses = model.ManyToManyField(ModelTwo)

class ModelFour(models.Model):
    now_this_is_just_silly = models.ManyToManyField(ModelThree)
```

So lets say I fetch  ModelFour like so:

```
m = ModelFour.objects.all()[0]
```

It would be wonderful to think that, by default, all submodels all the way down to `ModelOne` are a part of it's datastructure. Is that the case?

If I start to navigate down the datastructure of ModelFour to access an attribute (the stuff) in ModelOne, am I performing multiple queries?

*For the record, this is a postgres database setup, per django suggestion.*

Comment: have you tried printing the query being generated?

Comment: all those models are simply related. Models from one to three are not sub-models of ModelFour. Each model sits in its own DB table. The queryset `qs=ModelFour.objects.all()` results in a simple SQL `SELECT "appname_tablefour"."col1", "appname_tablefour"."col2"... FROM "appname_tablefour"`

Comment: regarding model inheritance, please refer to the official [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count nr of queries try using [connection from django.db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/models/#faq-databases-and-models) (make sure `DEBUG=True` in settings.py):

```
from django.db import connection

m = ModelFour.objects.all()[0]

print len(connection.queries)
```

...and if you just want to see the queries in a list, remove len

Answer (score 1):

You can look at postgres' query count and check it again after your query has finished

Use this query to read total number of transactions executed in all databases:

```
SELECT sum(xact_commit+xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database;
```

If you want the same counter for just one database, use:

```
SELECT xact_commit+xact_rollback FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = 'mydb';
```

credit to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/how-many-queries-per-second-is-my-postgres-executing

You can list the current running queries with:

```
SELECT datname,procpid,current_query FROM pg_stat_activity
```

from: http://chrismiles.info/systemsadmin/databases/articles/viewing-current-postgresql-queries/